# Openfoam: simplefoam: command not found

Tags: openfoam

I was trying to install OpenFoam exactly as mentioned on their website.
But when I run `simpleFoam -help` it says command not found, even after restarting my PC.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 lts.

When I run `tail ~/.bashrc`, this is the output

```
        . "/home/hell/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/hell/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

source /opt/openfoam9/etc/bashrc
```

Here are the contents of the directory `/opt/openfoam9/etc`

```
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T1600:/opt/openfoam9/etc$ ls
bashrc     cellModels     config.csh  controlDict  paraFoam    templates
caseDicts  codeTemplates  config.sh   cshrc        README.org  thermoData
```

But there is something which I don't understand.
When I run `source /opt/openfoam9/etc/bashrc` in the terminal, this is what I get `/home/hell/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 285: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: command not found`. But this has nothing to do with OpenFoam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong SE a for this question, but I would try disabling conda, get OpenFOAM to work, and then put the conda stuff back in.

Answer (score 0):

I never call the bashrc file in the system setting. just call it int the terminal you are working on.